# Giving Dynamic label to a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a dynamic form so on click of a button I call a Javascript function. here is the function:

```
function addradiobutton(type){
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("value", type);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);   

    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    counter=counter+1;
 }
```

This code adds a radio button and its tag is like this

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio">
```

But I want to  make this code like this.

```
 <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio">WATER</input>
```

I dont mind about closing input tag but I want to get the value 'Water' their at the end of the code. 
Water is just taken for example its value would be dynamic as well.
What should I do ?

Comment: You can't. To give a radio a label, you'll have to do this: `<input type="radio" id="demo" /><label for="demo">LABEL</label>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        function addradiobutton(type, text) {
            var label = document.createElement("label");

            var element = document.createElement("input");
            //Assign different attributes to the element.
            element.setAttribute("type", type);
            element.setAttribute("value", type);
            element.setAttribute("name", type);

            label.appendChild(element);
            label.innerHTML += text;

            var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
            //Append the element in page (in span).
            foo.appendChild(label);
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        addradiobutton("radio", "Water");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio">WATER</input>
```

… is invalid HTML. The way to express what you are trying to express is:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio">WATER</label>
```

You just need to create a label element, and then `appendChild` both the input element and the text node.

```
var label, input;
label = document.createElement('label');
input = document.createElement('input');
// Set type, name, value, etc on input
label.appendChild(input);
label.appendChild('Water');
foo.appendChild(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I would use is create it not like that but more: (using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for simplicity with syntax)

```
<div id="buttons">

</div>

<scrpit>
    var temp;
    temp = '<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio" />WATER</label>';
    temp + '<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio" />WATER1</label>';
    $('#buttons').html(temp);
</script>
```

Untested but the logic should work, i will try update for errors.

if you want x amount you could put it in a function with a for loop looping to x and iterating those out. Example:

```
<script>
    function addButtons(number){
        for(var i=0;i<number;i++){
            // do the string appending here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `<input></input>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```
element.setAttribute("innerHTML","WATER");
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. `innerHTML` isn't an attribute, and `<input>` elements are defined as EMPTY.