# Get properties of dynamically-defined, checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, radio-button

There are load of similar questions asked but I still can't figure it out.

I have a set of radio buttons, dynamically defined (both the number of buttons and the labels for them change).

I simply need to get the label and number associated with the checked radio button. How can I do this?

I made a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p1h8dqk/3/) showing that, when I click on any button, the checked radio is "undefined". Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myArray = ["never", "sometimes", "always"];

  for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    addradiobutton("radio", i + 1, label = myArray[i]);
  }

  function addradiobutton(type, number, text) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");

    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("value", number);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);
    element.setAttribute("id", "radio_" + number);

    label.appendChild(element);
    label.innerHTML += text;

    var foo = document.getElementById("questionAnswerRadio");
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(label);
  }

  $("#questionAnswerRadio").click(function(event) {
    var currentSlideResult = 0;
    currentSlideResult.answerChosen = $("#questionAnswerRadio :radio:checked + label").text();
    currentSlideResult.numberChosen = $("#questionAnswerRadio :radio:checked + value").text();
    alert(currentSlideResult.answerChosen)
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questionAnswerRadio"></div>
```

Comment: By the way, I got the addradiobutton function from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154488/giving-dynamic-label-to-a-radio-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `$(this)` inside the event handler to get the value and label of the clicked radio button
2. Assign empty object to the variable `currentSlideResult`
3. To get the label associated with the radio button use `$(this).parent().text()`
4. Use `change` event on radio instead of `click`
5. You can pass the array element directly to the function, no need to assign it to a variable and then pass the variable
6. To create new element and append element you can use jQuery

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9p1h8dqk/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myArray = ["never", "sometimes", "always"];

  for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    addradiobutton("radio", i + 1, myArray[i]);
  }

  function addradiobutton(type, number, text) {
    var input = $('<input />')
      .attr({
        type: type,
        value: number,
        name: type,
        id: 'radio_' + number
      });

    $('<label />')
      .text(text)
      .prepend(input)
      .appendTo('#questionAnswerRadio');
  }

  $("#questionAnswerRadio").on('change', ':radio', function(event) {
    var currentSlideResult = {};
    currentSlideResult.answerChosen = $(this).parent().text();
    currentSlideResult.numberChosen = $(this).val();
    alert(currentSlideResult.answerChosen);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questionAnswerRadio"></div>
```